# Strange hang and memory leak with OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory-leaks, openfiledialog

I'm experiencing a rather strange hang with an indefinitely climbing memory leak when calling OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog (.NET Framework 4.8). As shown in the [animated gif/video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouuvJ.jpg) (apologies for the lack of editing), there seems to be no noteworthy change in the snapshots regardless of how long I wait - even when it reaches multiple allocated gigabytes. Am I missing something regarding how to use the Memory Usage snapshot diagnostic tool?

The initial folder it tries to access doesn't have very many files and opening that same folder using FileDialog boxes in other applications (such as Visual Studio 2019) doesn't result in any problems.

There is no funky timer code anywhere in the application, it does run tasks (as shown below) to load the data in the background for a more responsive UI, however the dialog is intentionally loaded in a section of code where the logic path is guaranteed to be running on the UI thread to simplify matters. The same code worked fine for years, before, the only code I've added since this odd behaviour began is to add report printing functionality in an unrelated section of code.

Any ideas? Thanks.
Progress update:

- I have only one Shell extension (WinMerge), it's been working fine for years.
- I've tested the program in a VM and it works exactly as intended.
- I've downloaded the debug PDB symbols using the Microsoft and NuGet.org symbol servers, and the leak is definitely happening in unmanaged Windows code - the memory usage tool is referring to the leaked objects as an endlessly growing list of opaque (void*) memory addresses and values within an "Object Type"  named "unresolved allocations", unfortunately. A sample callstack is as follows:

```
ntdll.dll!NtTraceEvent()  
ntdll.dll!RtlpLogHeapFreeEvent()  
ntdll.dll!RtlpFreeHeap()  
ntdll.dll!RtlpFreeHeapInternal()  
ntdll.dll!RtlFreeHeap()  
ntdll.dll!RtlDebugFreeHeap()  
ntdll.dll!RtlpFreeHeap()  
ntdll.dll!RtlpFreeHeapInternal()  
ntdll.dll!RtlFreeHeap()  
KernelBase.dll!LocalFree()  
ExplorerFrame.dll!CTContainer_PolicyLocalMem::DestroyMem(void *)  
ExplorerFrame.dll!TabletModeHelpers::GetMonitorConfig(int *, bool *)  
ExplorerFrame.dll!SHIsFileExplorerInTabletMode(void)  
ExplorerFrame.dll!UICheckbox::OnHosted()  
dui70.dll!DirectUI::Element::OnHosted()  
ExplorerFrame.dll!UIItem::OnHosted(class DirectUI::Element *)  
dui70.dll!DirectUI::Element::OnPropertyChanged()  
ExplorerFrame.dll!UIItem::OnPropertyChanged()  
dui70.dll!DirectUI::Element::_PostSourceChange()  
dui70.dll!DirectUI::Element::Insert()  
ExplorerFrame.dll!UICollection::_CreateAndInsertItems()  
ExplorerFrame.dll!UICollection::_RealizeItems()  
ExplorerFrame.dll!UICollection::RealizeSection(class SectionInfo *)  
ExplorerFrame.dll!LineScroller::_RealizeDirectionWorker()  
ExplorerFrame.dll!LineScroller::_RealizeDirectionWorker()  
ExplorerFrame.dll!LineScroller::_RealizeDirectionWorker()  
ExplorerFrame.dll!LineScroller::_RealizeAroundAnchor()  
ExplorerFrame.dll!LineScroller::_RealizeContent()  
ExplorerFrame.dll!LineScroller::_LayoutContent()  
ExplorerFrame.dll!LineScroller::_Viewer_SelfLayoutDoLayout(int,int)  
dui70.dll!DirectUI::Element::_FlushLayout()  
dui70.dll!DirectUI::Element::_FlushLayout()  
dui70.dll!DirectUI::Element::_FlushLayout()  
dui70.dll!DirectUI::Element::_FlushLayout()  
dui70.dll!DirectUI::Element::_FlushLayout()  
dui70.dll!DirectUI::DeferCycle::_EndDefer()  
dui70.dll!DirectUI::Element::EndDefer()  
dui70.dll!DirectUI::Element::_PostSourceChange()  
dui70.dll!DirectUI::Element::_SetValue()  
dui70.dll!DirectUI::Element::SetValue(struct DirectUI::PropertyInfo const * (*)(void),int,class DirectUI::Value *)  
ExplorerFrame.dll!LineViewer::SetLayoutState(int)  
ExplorerFrame.dll!LineScroller::_EnsureRealizePass(void)  
ExplorerFrame.dll!LineScroller::_OnLayoutChangeEvent(struct LayoutChangeEvent *)  
ExplorerFrame.dll!LineScroller::OnEvent()  
dui70.dll!DirectUI::Element::s_HandleDUIEventMessage(class DirectUI::Element *,struct EventMsg *)  
dui70.dll!DirectUI::Element::_DisplayNodeCallback()  
duser.dll!GPCB::xwInvokeDirect()  
duser.dll!SafeMsgQ::xwProcessNL()  
duser.dll!SafeMsgQ::xwProcessNL(void)  
duser.dll!CoreSC::xwProcessMsgQNL(void)  
duser.dll!CoreSC::xwProcessNL()  
duser.dll!MphProcessMessage()  
user32.dll!__ClientGetMessageMPH()  
ntdll.dll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue()  
win32u.dll!NtUserPeekMessage()  
user32.dll!_PeekMessage()  
user32.dll!DialogBox2()  
user32.dll!InternalDialogBox()  
user32.dll!DialogBoxIndirectParamAorW()  
user32.dll!DialogBoxIndirectParamW()  
comdlg32.dll!<lambda>(void)()  
comdlg32.dll!CFileOpenSave::Show(struct HWND__*)  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.RunDialogVista(System.IntPtr hWndOwner)  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window owner)  
Bingo.exe!OPEQ.frmBingo.tsmiFileOpen_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 1098
```

```
private void tsmiFileOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Logging.Method();
    //Gets the filter description retrieval task for the dialog
    //box which was begun at program launch (if this fails or has
    //yet to complete, the initial value is used instead).
    CultureInfo uiCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
    TaskParams openDialogFilterTaskParams;

    if (_tasks.TryGetValue(_fileDialogFilterTaskKey, out openDialogFilterTaskParams))
    {
        bool removeFromTasks = false;
        //If we can, get the result, otherwise use the existing filter.
        switch (openDialogFilterTaskParams.Task.Status)
        {
            case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
                //Update the filter variable.
                var odfTask = (Task<IDictionary<CultureInfo, FileDialogFilterList>>)openDialogFilterTaskParams.Task;
                foreach (var kvPair in odfTask.Result)
                {
                    //If any GetFileTypeName call fails, the resulting
                    //description is null, so we need to
                    //account for that here.
                    var updatedList = ReplaceNullDescriptions(kvPair.Value, kvPair.Key);
                    _openDialogFilterDict[kvPair.Key] = updatedList.CopyEmbellished().ToString();
                }
                removeFromTasks = true;
                break;
            case TaskStatus.Canceled:
            case TaskStatus.Faulted:
                removeFromTasks = true;
                //Use the filter's initial value.
                break;
            default:
                //Use the filter's initial value.
                break;
        }
        if (removeFromTasks)
        {
            try
            {
                //The Wait() here is intentional to avoid
                //making this event handler async.
                openDialogFilterTaskParams.Task.Wait(openDialogFilterTaskParams.TokenSource.Token);
            }
            catch(OperationCanceledException)
            {
                //Swallow cancellation.
            }
            catch (AggregateException aggEx) when (aggEx.InnerExceptions.Any(ex => !(ex is OperationCanceledException)))
            {
                //Log and swallow the exception(s).
                Logging.Exception(aggEx,
                    isRecoverableError: true,
                    includeStackTrace: true);
            }
            finally
            {
                openDialogFilterTaskParams.Task.Dispose();
                openDialogFilterTaskParams.TokenSource.Dispose();
                _tasks.TryRemove(_fileDialogFilterTaskKey, out _);
            }
        }
    }

    //Dialog box guarantees the user-specified file exists.     
    //No need to handle initial directory, it handles that on its own.
    openFileDialog1.Filter = _openDialogFilterDict[uiCulture];
    openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = _openDialogDefaultExtension;
    //Program hangs on this next line.
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //Handle the creation, dictionary addition and retrieval as one atomic operation.
        var fileLoadTaskParams = _tasks.GetOrAdd(_fileLoadingTaskKey, (_, fnames) =>
        {
            TaskParams tParam = new TaskParams(
                null,
                null,
                new Progress<ReportLoaderProgressChangedEventArgs>());
            try
            {
                tParam.TokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(_tidyShutdownCts.Token);
                tParam.Task = new ReportLoader(fnames).LoadAsync(tParam.TokenSource.Token, (IProgress<ReportLoaderProgressChangedEventArgs>)tParam.Additional);
            }
            catch
            {
                tParam.TokenSource?.Dispose();
                tParam.Task?.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
            return tParam;
        }, openFileDialog1.FileNames.AsEnumerable());

        //Set the default scan-type mode
        //(Search if multiple files were loaded,
        //Verification if only one).
        _scanModeSelected = openFileDialog1.FileNames.Length > 1
            ? tsBtnScanType_Search
            : tsBtnScanType_Verification;

        /* Hand off the contents of the retrieved tuple to
         * LoadFile(...). This means LoadFile handles the display
         * of any non-critical exceptions to the user, anything
         * dangerous will bubble out of it and into FireAndForget at
         * which point the application is allowed to die.*/
        LoadFile(
            (Task<OPEQReportDataSet>)fileLoadTaskParams.Task,
            fileLoadTaskParams.TokenSource,
            (Progress<ReportLoaderProgressChangedEventArgs>)fileLoadTaskParams.Additional)
            .FireAndForget(null, null, () =>
            {
                fileLoadTaskParams.Task.Dispose();
                fileLoadTaskParams.TokenSource?.Dispose();
                _tasks.TryRemove(_fileLoadingTaskKey, out _);
            });
    } //if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
}
```

2nd Progress Update:
...and it's now working again without explanation. I guess it was indeed a Windows Update. (?!)

Comment: Does this behavior persist when run this code on another machine?

Comment: I haven't tried running this bugged version on another system yet, I can try that tomorrow though.

Comment: I suggest you use a memory profiler like ANTS to see what's going on. I feel sure I've seen this question before, did you delete and repost?

Comment: @Charlieface yeah, I need an answer sooner than later and I felt like the automatic -1 at the end of the day with the 2 votes to close the question because I didn't end up adding the code until today would discourage people from taking a look, so I opted for a fresh start

Comment: As the OpenFileDialog is in fact a Windows Explorer, any kind of external stuff can kick in here, e.g. Shell Extensions. If it does not occur on a fresh Windows installation, it's not your fault.

Comment: Like I said, you need to do some debugging yourself as we cannot see this issue. Otherwise you may get close votes again. If you can show us at least what it is that is leaking memory, perhaps we can work out why it is doing so.

Comment: @Charlieface If I knew what was leaking memory, I wouldn't be asking for help. :)

Comment: If there is no memory leak when running the program on the VM, then perhaps the .NET version needs to be upgraded on the computer with the memory leak. Are the .NET versions the same or different?

Comment: Given that it appears to be an issue with unmanaged code, have you tried updating Windows to the latest build? A good memory profiler should be able to filter things like `IDisposable`, there is always a chance it is on the .NET side somehow.